# How do I write a shell script to remove the unzipped files in a wrong directory?

Tags: shell

I accidentally unzipped files into a wrong directory, actually there are hundreds of files... now the directory is messed up with the original files and the wrongly unzip files. I want to pick the unzipped files and remove them using shell script, e.g.

```
$unzip foo.zip -d test_dir
$cd target_dir
$ls test_dir | rm -rf
```

nothing happened, no files were deleted, what's wrong with my command ? Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following script has two main benefits over the other answers thus far:

1. It does not require you to unzip a whole 2nd copy to a temp dir (I just list the file names)
2. It works on files that may contain spaces (parsing `ls` will break on spaces)

---

```
while read -r _ _ _ file; do
  arr+=("$file")
done < <(unzip -qql foo.zip)
rm -f "${arr[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Right way to do this is with xargs:

```
$find ./test_dir -print | xargs rm -rf
```

**Edited** Thanks SiegeX to explain to me OP question.

This 'read' wrong files from test dir and remove its from target dir.

```
$unzip foo.zip -d /path_to/test_dir
$cd target_dir
(cd /path_to/test_dir ; find ./ -type f -print0 ) | xargs -0 rm
```

I use `find -0` because filenames can contain blanks and  newlines. But if not is your case, you can run with `ls`:

```
$unzip foo.zip -d /path_to/test_dir
$cd target_dir
(cd /path_to/test_dir ; ls ) | xargs rm -rf
```

before to execute you should test script changing `rm` by `echo`

Comment: this will delete the files in './test_dir' since `find` prints the whole path

Comment: to avoid first `cd target_dir`, just replace `test_dir` by `target_dir/test_dir` in command: `find ./target_dir/test_dir -print ...`. @SiegeX, is this that you are talking about? Please, be free to edit my answer.

Comment: Your command is deleting all files in `./test_dir`, this isn't what the OP wants.  Instead, he wants to use the file names in `./test_dir` to delete files in `target_dir`

Comment: Thanks @SiegeX to explain to me OP question.

Comment: np. Good for you to use `-print0 | xargs -0`

Comment: thanks @SiegeX, please, be free now to improve my english grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 for file in $( unzip -qql FILE.zip | awk '{ print $4 }'); do
     rm -rf DIR/YOU/MESSED/UP/$file
 done
```

`unzip -l` list the content with a bunch of information about the zipped files. You just have to grep the file name out of it.

EDIT: using `-qql` as suggested by SiegeX

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me (bash)

```
unzip -l filename.zip | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs rm -Rf
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$ ls test_dir | xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `ls test_dir | xargs rm -rf` as your last command

#### Why:

`rm` doesn't take input from stdin so you can't pipe the list of files to it. `xargs` takes the output of `ls` command and presents it to `rm` as input so that it can delete it.

Comment: @user1165196 You're welcome!! I added an explanation as to why it does not work. `xargs` stands for `eXecute ARGumentS` and here it provides `rm` a list of files as arguments to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Compacting the previous one. Run this command in the /DIR/YOU/MESSED/UP

```
unzip -qql FILE.zip | awk '{print "rm -rf  " $4 }' | sh
```

enjoy